# Youtube makes my secure server unsecure?

Tags: security, youtube, web

The Youtube video make my website insecure, and I need it to be secure, what do I do to make it secure even though I have a Youtube video embeded? Simply I need my users to link videos.

[image]

I haven't really tried much since i searched the web and tried to research the issue but couldn't find any..

Answer (score 0):

Change the `http://` in the URL to video into `//`.